# NamedParameterJdbcTemplate query method returning wrong integer value

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jdbctemplate, sqlparameter

I am running a simple mysql query using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate in java.

The problem is that my java query is returning binary values for the *count* field i.e **1 for all non-zero values** and **0 for all zero values**. When I run the same query that jdbc is sending to mysql, directly on mysql server I get the correct answer.

Details below:

Here is the query:

```
SELECT CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT :fieldName) AS UNSIGNED) count, user_id userId FROM "+ tableName + " WHERE user_id IN (:userIdList) GROUP BY userId
```

The java LOC that does the query:

```
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedJdbcTemplate = new   NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource());

    List<CountRow> countRows = namedJdbcTemplate.query(query,parameters,new CountRowMapper());
```

The countRow class is:

```
public class CountRow {
private int count;
private String userId;

public CountRow() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}
public void setCount(int count) {
    this.count = count;
}

public int getCount() {
    return count;
}

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}
```

}

The details for the columns that I am querying:

```
  `user_id` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `fieldName` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Finally, my jdbc connection url is:

```
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/mydb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;useSSL=false&amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF8&amp;characterSetResults=UTF8
```

I am completely clueless about why this is happening. It would be really great if somebody could shed some light on this.

Thanks

Comment: When you're using parameters, what you get in the end will not be a reference to a table - it will be a static string or number value, like this: `select count(distinct 'id') from my_table`. Which basically returns 0 if no rows match predicate, and 1 if at least one row matches (all rows return same value, "id").

Comment: I can not believe that I missed this yet again. Thank you for pointing out my sheer negligence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you can use the parameter `:fieldName` in that way.
try to build the sql query using concatenation as you did with `tablename`

```
"SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT " + fieldName + ") count, user_id userId 
FROM "+ tableName + " WHERE user_id IN (:userIdList) GROUP BY userId
```

Hope this helps

Comment: As I commented above, the mistake was as silly as they come and it seems that I always fall for it. Anyways, thanks for the answer, hopefully I would not fall for this again. Cheers!